# Having a specific element of StackPanel centered in the application in wpf .net core application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, alignment, stackpanel

I am currently developing a map application with a floating time selector in the bottom of the application:
[image]

so far, so good. The time selector on the bottom is implemented the following way:

```xml
<DockPanel Grid.ZIndex ="2" Height="Auto"  HorizontalAlignment ="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,20">
        <!-- Play/Pause button for map time -->
        <Button x:Name="MapTime_PlayPause_Button" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height ="30" Width ="30" Margin="0,0,20,0" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="{x:Null}" >
            <Button.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="/play_Button_40x40.png"/>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <!-- Map Time Slider -->
        <Slider x:Name="MapTime_Slider" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width ="200" SmallChange="1" Minimum="-55" Maximum="0" Value="-55" TickPlacement="BottomRight" ValueChanged="MapTime_Slider_ValueChanged" />
        <!-- Map Time Display -->
        <Label x:Name="MapTime_Label" Height="40" Foreground="#FF5AE00D" Background="#FF303030" Margin="10,0,0,0" Content="-55" FontSize="22" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </StackPanel>
</DockPanel>
```

The issue is the following: The whole stack panel is centered on the screen - fine.
As soon as I use the slider, the issue appears. The slider updates the `MapTime_Label` to the right of it. Due to the number increasing or decreasing, the width of the label changes.
Therefore the alignment of the whole stack panel changes and the slider becomes totally unpredictable:

[image]

Notice how the Play button at the start of the gif is to the right of the lake. As soon as I use the slider and the number changes, it jumps over to the left of the lake.

In the end, I will have integer rather than float. The above example is exaggerating the issue. With integer I have the issue still when transitioning between digit lengths such as -100 (4 chars) to -99 (3 chars) or -1 (2chars) to 0 (1 char)

Any idea on how to have the slider at the center of the screen whilst letting the button and label wrap around as is?

Comment: This is typical layout problem, container is centered, but while you change value it change its children width and re-center itself.

Comment: Yes you are right. do you have a suggested Solution? Im thinking of using -yet another- grid within the container but im not sure if that's the right approach and if it can be solved that way.

Comment: Set precision of result to 2 decimal places so slider doesn't move.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.slider.autotooltipprecision?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: hello jdweng, I have disabled decimal places entirely now, only showing the int value. But:
-100 -> -99  wobble; -10 -> -9 Wobble; -1 -> 0 Wobble - Basically anytime there is a transition from at a tens digit

Comment: You can use fixed width for an element with black background. Or move it out of centered container and left-align it to the right (may be tricky, centering has to be done with `Grid`, use invisible `*` grid columns on both sides).

Comment: If some 0 at the beginning is acceptable for your requirements (for example -099 is acceptable for indicating -99) then you might use `StringFormat=D3`